# How to query data in druid?

Tags: druid

I am following druid documentation but as i run the command

```
curl -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d @quickstart/tutorial/wikipedia-top-pages.json http://localhost:8082/druid/v2?pretty
```

I get the response

```
[]
```

What is the matter? I have also quickstart folder in my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your druid console -> datasources. You will find name of your datasource and replace datasource name in `wikipedia-top-pages.json` to your datasource name.